# Proving $x\preceq y \implies \bar{\bar{x}} \leq \bar{\bar{y}}$ in cardinal arithmetic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $\bar{\bar{x}}$ denote the cardinal of $x$ and $\approx$ denote bijective equivalence.

Assume $x\preceq y$. By definition $\exists z (z \subseteq y \land x \approx z)$. Now from something I've already proven as $x \approx z$ then  $\bar{\bar{x}} = \bar{\bar{z}}$. Thus all I need to prove is that $z \subseteq y \to  \bar{\bar{z}} \leq  \bar{\bar{y}}$. As cardinals are just ordinals I've attempted to prove this by contradiction. I.e assume $ \bar{\bar{y}} <  \bar{\bar{z}}$, so $ \bar{\bar{y}} \in  \bar{\bar{z}}$. Now as $z \approx  \bar{\bar{z}}$ and $y \approx  \bar{\bar{y}}$ I think that our assumption should lead to a contradiction of the fact that $z \subseteq y$.

I don't know why but after a few pages of scratchings I'm not able to clearly reach the desired contradiction. This seems like it should be a simple proof so I don't know if I'm going down the wrong path or if I'm missing something glaringly obvious. I was able to prove the converse in a few lines. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you not simply lift the identity map from $z$ into $y$ to an injection from $\bar{\bar z}$ into $\bar{\bar y}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here, but the key is to use the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein Theorem. Assume by way of contradiction that $\bar{\bar y}<\bar{\bar x}$. Then $y\approx \bar{\bar y}\subset \bar{\bar x}\approx x$ by the transitivity property of the ordinals. Hence $y\preceq x$. By the C-S-B Theorem then $y\approx x$. Hence $\bar{\bar y}=\bar{\bar x}$, contradiction.

Comment: CSB is not really needed; like Brian said, any injection from $x$ to $y$ induces an injection from $\bar{\bar{x}}$ to $\bar{\bar{y}}$.